# Django Change Root URL

Tags: python, django, apache

I am trying to complete the Django starter [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/).

I have the site working fine on the django test web server. I am trying to get it working on Apache.

I have setup Apache so `http://mydomain.com/mysite/` will get to the Django root project (mysite). However I cannot get to Polls, because I think it's expecting `http://mydomain.com/polls/`

How do I change the projects root url from `http://mydomain.com/polls/` to `http://mydomain.com/mysite/polls` ?

I have tried the following in the root urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^mysite/' include('mysite')),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

But it isn't working. I have searched through as much documentation as I can find, and I can't find the answer to this.

My Apache config is as follows:

```
WSGIScriptAlias "/mysite/" /usr/local/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /usr/local/mysite

<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Directory /usr/local/mysite/mysite>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Order deny,allow
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

@scriptmonsters answer changed the root URL, however now Apache is appending everything after the root url to the location of the wscgi file. So if I try http://myhost.com/mysite/polls/ I get `not found` and this in the apache log:

```
[Wed Nov 06 12:49:23 2013] [error] [client 109.144.246.190] Target WSGI script not found or unable to stat: /usr/local/mysite/mysite/wsgi.pypolls
```

(note that the file it tried to access is `wsgi.pyPOLLS`)

Comment: @Alasdair I have edited the post with the Apache config and the error apache is giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^mysite/polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^mysite/admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```